# Tensorflow, how to chain GRU layers

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow

Right now I am trying to chain multiple GRU recurrent layers to each other in tensorflow.  I am getting the following error.

```
ValueError: Variable GRUCell/Gates/Linear/Matrix already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True in VarScope? Originally defined at:

  File "/home/chase/workspace/SentenceEncoder/sent_enc.py", line 42, in <module>
    output, states[i] = grus[i](output, states[i])
```

Here is my code.

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (batch_size, time_steps, vlen), 'x')
y_exp = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (batch_size, time_steps, vlen), 'y_exp')

with tf.name_scope('encoder'):
    gru_sizes = (128, 256, 512)
    grus = [tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell(sz) for sz in gru_sizes]
    states = [tf.zeros((batch_size, g.state_size)) for g in grus]
    for t in range(time_steps):
        output = tf.reshape(x[:, t, :], (batch_size, vlen))
        for i in range(len(grus)):
            output, states[i] = grus[i](output, states[i])
```

I am aware that tensorflow provides a MultiRNNCell for doing this but I kind of wanted to figure it out for myself.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix it.  I needed to add a different variable scope for each of the layers.  I also needed to reuse the variables after the first time step.

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (batch_size, time_steps, vlen), 'x')
y_exp = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (batch_size, time_steps, vlen), 'y_exp')

with tf.name_scope('encoder'):
    gru_sizes = (128, 256, 512)
    grus = [tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell(sz) for sz in gru_sizes]
    states = [tf.zeros((batch_size, g.state_size)) for g in grus]
    for t in range(time_steps):
        output = tf.reshape(x[:, t, :], (batch_size, vlen))
        for i in range(len(grus)):
            with tf.variable_scope('gru_' + str(i), reuse = t > 0):
                output, states[i] = grus[i](output, states[i])
```